# maximum size for xml files

Tags: xml

whats your rule of thumb for maximum size for xml files.

What if I ask maximum no of records, and one record have 10 values for instance? Another condition is we are loading it from web.

Comment: You forgot to mention: maximum "for what".

Answer (score 20):

My rule is that **if it's too slow to do what I want, then it's too big**, and your data probably needs to be moved to some other format... database or such.

Traversing XML nodes or using XPath can be a dog.

Answer (score 7):

This may be not the thing you want to hear, but... If you're thinking about the size of your XML files, chances are you should use a database instead of files (even if they are not flat files but structured like XML). Databases are highly optimized for efficient storage of huge masses of data. The best algorithms for retrieving data are in the code base of databases.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't any. There are maximum sizes for files that depend on the file system you are using, though.

Comment: We're talking about a rule of thumb here.

Comment: He's saying there is no rule of thumb.

Answer (score 1):

There is **no limit of XML file** **size** but it takes **memory (RAM)** as **file size of XML file**, so **long XML file** parsing size is **performance hit**.
It is advised to **long XML size** using **[SAX for .NET](http://saxdotnet.sourceforge.net/)** to parse long XML documents.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should have a rule of thumb for maximum size for data, be it XML or anything else. If you need to store multiple gigabytes of data, then you store that data. What makes a difference is what API you use to process that data. However, XML may not be your best bet if your data set is very large. In those cases a relational or XML database will probably work better than a single XML file.

Comment: You are totally right... just as long as you never want to access the data in a half-reasonable time

Comment: @Galwegian: Well, what do you do then? Delete half the data?

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on the context, where the file comes from/is generated from, what you are going to do with it, the bandwidth of any connection it has to pass through, system RAM size etc?

what is your context?

Answer (score 0):

Even though not all parsers read the whole file into memory, if you really need a rule of thumb I would say not bigger than half of your available ram. Anything bigger will likely be way too slow :)

Answer (score -1):

I worked on a project in 2010 where by i had to move a newspaper website from Typo 3 to Drupal 7 and the fastest way around at the time was to export all the content as xml and then parse them into drupal(Xpath). We tried doing it in one go but we had problems at 4Gigs .. So we divided the xmls per year and had each file have less time to parse and the file size in MBs and that went fine. Other reads suggest that the max file may depend on your ram.