# About XML file size limitation

Tags: c#, xml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [maximum size for xml files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132330/maximum-size-for-xml-files)

I have developed an application which uses xml file as a datasource . but i don't know any limitations of the xml file usage.

I want to know the limitations of the xml file according to the size of the xml data. because i'd searched on google & i got result like xml is not useful when the xml data size is out of limit that time may be your application performance slows down . but i'm unable to finding that limit of the xml data.

can anybody help me?

thanx....

Comment: To some extent, parsing performance will depend on the structure of your xml, beyond that it's the maximum file size

Comment: Top voted answer on the duplicate question: "My rule is that if it's too slow to do what I want, then it's too big, and your data probably needs to be moved to some other format... database or such." Amen!

Comment: Your problem seems to be that you refuse to consider a solution that moves away from using XML as a database. If XML doesn't work because you've got too much data then you have to stop using XML. You can't really entertain the idea of limiting the size of your database can you? Who's going to want to live with that limitation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no inherent limit, but you should ask yourself how much data is going to be stored as XML and how much it's going to be used. XML parsing is relatively slow, and if you use it a lot it can become a performance problem.

XML is great for small and medium-sized files. If you have very simple data you might want to go with a flat-file format. If you have a lot of data, or the data is very complicated, you might want to use something fancier than XML, like a database or a custom binary format.

Can you post some more information about what kind of information is stored in the XML files? That would help us determine if XML is the right tool for the job.

Comment: i'm developing an application software for the corporate world & my software must store the information about the employees contact related information & there is not any limitation of the no of employees in the industry. so how can i told the exact size of the xml file?

Comment: @priyank: use a database

Comment: There's no need to worry about the exact size of the data. In your case, there's going to be a lot of data, and that's the important part (like you said, there's no limit on the number of people in the industry). So I agree with Mitch. It's worth investing the effort in a database.

Comment: but i don't want to use any database server like sql server. i've to give the answer to my boss about the xml file size limitation. he willing to know that exact size of the xml file. then that time i can't tell these answers to him. can u tell me the exact file size limitation?

Comment: should i go with the sqlite for my application?

Comment: That's a complicated question. If you're using .NET, in my experience SQL Server works well. If you don't want to use SQL Server, in general I think SQLite is a good database, but I haven't used it personally.

Unfortunately, there isn't an exact size where XML becomes slow. It gradually slows down as the file size increases. If your program already uses XML, I would try to guess (and only guess) how big the files are going to be. Then make some files of that size and run the program on them. That's usually the best way to tell if the program is "fast enough".

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no limit in XML size, what wud be the size of xml data you are expecting?

Using large XML is alwasy performance hit, XMLDocument.Load()  takes the memory as the size of XML file on disk. If  you have have 10 MB xml file and 2000 users logs on to the site and opens the xml file, 2GB limit of the virtual address space of IIS worker process will be used and your application will crash.

Be careful to open huge xml file using xmldocument.

Comment: I'm willing to develop an application which uses xml file with size  50 MB . And i 'm using .net 2005 & language for my application is c#.net . but i'm not sure about the speed of the data retrial from that much big file. can u give me any suggestion on this?

Answer (score 1):

There is not inherent limit if you use XmlReader. The xml is parsed one token at a time, so the memory footprint is very very low. BUT if you want to read it as an XmlDocument OR XDocument (the LINQ version) then all the XML is loaded in memory, and it's bigger in memory than on disk (because in memory, in c#, it's UTF-16 so 2 bytes for each char, while on disk you normally keep it UTF-8, so 1 byte for many "West-World" char (A-Za-z0-9 and punctuation). And then in memory there are flocks of XmlElement and XmlAttributes and whatever.
XmlSerialier I think read the Xml one "block" at a time (one object), so no problem here, unless you have too many objects (but this isn't probably your problem)

Answer (score 0):

no limit.
If you read a large .xml file, it takes more time.
if you don`t want to slow down your application, just use the powerful xml parse(rapidxml which is used in boost library.), or you can use use binary data.

Comment: as you told that if the size of the xml file increases then the application requires more time. but i want to know that size of xml file. because i'm not sure about actual size of my xml file it might be up to 50 MB. so what can i do now?